# How can i use an outer source of text input( ex. Scanner) to input data without having an HTML input field?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have attached my usb scanner to the pc. it works well with a normal input field. But i dont want to show the field box. I only want to read the Data through scanning.

I tried hidding the input field by using **input type="hidden"**. that hides the field but data doesnt pass.
I tried **display:none;** same as before.
And Finally i tried vanishing the field's **border/outline** But it was useless.

Answer (score 0):

Just Figured out that setting the **z-index: -1** does the trick. If there's a better option let me know